# Does the tzitzti need to be 7/8/11/13?

Tags: tzitzis

Many Ashknezaim follow the custom to have the strings tied between the knots 7 times, then 8 times, then 11 times, then 13 times. However, if one were to have tzitzit that were otherwise kosher but in between the knots it was tied a different amount (doesn't matter how many for the purposes of curiosity), would this still be a kosher pair of tzitzit, or would the pair be pasul if it was not tied 7/8/11/13?

Comment: The Sefardim have a different minhag as to number of turns of the string. So it is unlikely to be possul mideoraisso. See https://blog.worldofjudaica.com/jewish-culture/tzitzit-tying-and-knots-guide/

Comment: The short answer is, "No." The windings follow minhag generally and there are many different customs across the entire Jewish people. The 7, 8, 11, and 13 winding order for the 'krachim' of the 'chuliyot' is attributed to the Ari z"l by his primary student, Rabbi Chaim Vital. Some customs have different windings between the Tallit Gadol and the Tallit Katan. Some Sefardim follow the custom from Rabbi Shlomo Molcho for example that the windings to the Tallit Katan are 10, 5, 6, and 5, following G-d's name.

Comment: @YaacovDeane In fact, the Mechaber gives the numbers 7, 9, 11 and 13, and the Nosei Keilim there correct the second one to 8 based (as you said) on the Arizal.

Comment: You start off saying "Many Ashknezaim follow the custom" and then ask whether not following it disqualifies the _tzitzis_?  -1.